# Она - сиделка, он - ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сказать о мужчине, если он исполняет роль сиделки? Сиделец?)))Иногда это нужно, но уме не приложу, как правильно написать.
Спасибо

Comment: Такие вещи всегда можно обойти. Женщина, конечно, сиделка, а мужчину с такими же функциями можно назвать человеком, ухаживающим за больным. Кстати, по моему наблюдению, слово "сиделка" употребляется все реже.

Comment: Он - слесарь, она - ?

Comment: У меня сиделка в списке активных слов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так и пишите, что сиделка. Нет тут приемлемого мужского варианта.
Есть профессии, которые не имеют нужных форм для представителей одного из гендерных родов. Чаще, правда, для мужского, но для женского тоже хватает: няня, медсестра, машинистка, балерина и проч. 
Если по контексту возникают двусмысленности или же проблемы с грамматическим согласованием, пишите мужчина-сиделка.

Comment: Вообще-то медбрат существует.

Comment: Подозревал, что кто-нибудь о об этом брате вспомнит. Ну да, существует, в семье не без урода.))) 
Не буду сейчас объяснять, почему я сильно сомневаюсь в нормативности "медбрата". Здесь важно то, что этот вариант образован не прямым суффиксальным словообразованием к исходному, а от другого корня (в каком-то смысле это своего рода супплетивизм).

Comment: а как же Усатый Нянь?:))))))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

Она сиделка, он (напрашивается!)сиделец

Comment: Она сиделка, а он сидел:)

Comment: У меня - словообразование с суффиксом "-ец". У Вас нелогично: "Он сидел, а она сидела":)

Answer (score 0):

Сиделка надеется на суму,а сиделец-на тюрьму.Сиделка ждет заключения врача,а сиделец-конца заключения.